# single, short Rspec test takes 80 seconds?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

can anyone tell me why this spec takes more than 80 seconds to complete?

```
require 'spec_helper'
include Features
include SessionHelpers

describe "Battles", focus: true do
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create :user }

  describe "view battle setup" do
    it "should open battle screen" do
        sign_in(user)
      click_button("join", :match => :first)
      fill_in "Name", with: "testname"
      click_button "Create"
        click_link("Events")
        click_button("Select", :match => :first)
        click_button("battle", :match => :first)
        expect(page).to have_content user.character.army.first.name
    end

  end
end
```

Comment: Ah, same guy asking, same question, just a repost from yesterday ... **Vote Close!**

Comment: Is this an isolated issue?

Comment: no pretty much every of my tests act this way

Comment: On windows? Rather use mac or linux (vm if you must) - it is a lot faster